# Proper way of showing tip on a ListView element

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a Fragment which contains a ListView. The elements of ListView are RecyclerViews which scroll horizontally. Each element of the RecyclerView is a CardView which contains some elements such as ImageViews and TextViews. I have to display a tip on a TextView inside that CardView.

This tip has to be displayed on the TextView in the first CardView of the first RecyclerView of the ListView. I am using [ShowTipsView](https://github.com/fredericojssilva/ShowTipsView) library to show the tips. What is the correct way of showing this tip?

Should I put some code inside the adapters of the ListView or RecyclerView or could it be done from the Fragment's code itself?

The real problem that I face is, how do I get access to the specific view(TextView) inside my Fragment's code?

Answer (score 0):

I found this from your given link:

```
ShowTipsView showtips = new ShowTipsBuilder(this)
    .setTarget(btn_test)
    .setTitle("A magnific button")
    .setDescription("This button do nothing so good")
    .setDelay(1000)
    .build();

showtips.show(this);
```

I see that `setTarget(xxx)` accepts a `View`. So you can do this in your `fragment` because it has your views.

Comment: I know this. But, how do I get access to that TextView in the Fragment?

Comment: @AmitTiwari Where are you initialising your `TextView`?

Comment: Inside the adapter for the RecyclerView.

Comment: Since it is a recycler view it would have more that one text views(in a list), am i right?

Comment: ya, it has and I want to show the tip on a specific one.

Comment: hmm, then i guess you should keep your tip on some static view as keeping it on a dynamic view may result in creating multiple tips.

Comment: there is a method in this library called `displayOneTime()` which can be used to display the tip only once. Earlier, I had put a transparent view at approximate position of that TextView in the layout of ListView row and I was showing the tip in the `getView()` of ListView adapter for that placeholder.

Comment: But, I want to make it programatically correct because I am having problem on different kind of devices. Also I am getting OutOfMemory errors in the emulator.

Comment: @AmitTiwari  You can try that `displayOneTime()` inside your `adapter` in `onCreateViewHolder()`. Then display the tip. If `displayOneTime()` doesn't work, you can create a flag which can check if tip is displayed then don't display again.

Comment: I can try that. But there is another problem. I have to show 4 tips. 2 of them are inside the row layout for ListView and 2 of them(including the Textview) are inside the row layout for RecyclerView. So I could show the first 2 in ListView's adapter and other 2 in RecyclerView's adapter. But I have to show the RecyclerView tips only after user has read the initial 2 tips. So, how do I get the callbacks from ListView's adapter to RecyclerView's adapter?

Comment: I have to show these tips in succession as soon as the user clicks the 'Got It' button for each tip. I think this is only possible once I have access to all four views at one place, inside the fragment.

Comment: You can create you own call back but i won't suggest that, it will make your code hell lot of mess. It would be better if you can do it from one place, as you said.